# Como incluir Crystal reports en un instalador de C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tengo problemas al incluir crystal reports ya que la ruta del reporte corresponde a la computadora en la que se elaboro el software y al generar el instalador mantiene esa misma ruta.
adjunto una imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo creaste el instalador, usaste la publicación de Visual Studio?

Comment: si, justamente hice el ejecutable con una extencion de Visual Studio que genera un Setup.